# CollectionView flash when reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, flash, parse-platform

I have a collectionView which is populated with around 60 images downloading from parse. These images can be updated depending if any new ones have been uploaded.

But my problem is after I load the view, and I refresh the data using PullToRefresh function, the collection view **Flashes white** and then displays the images again...

here's a video to show you :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qizaAbUnzYQ&feature=youtu.be

I have been trying to fix this all day & find a solution, but I have had no success..!

Heres how I'm querying the images :

```
 func loadPosts() {
     self.activityView.startAnimating()
        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follows")
        followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.followArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                        for object in objects! {
                            self.followArray.append(object.valueForKey("following") as! String)

                        }

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.limit = self.page
        query.whereKey("username", notContainedIn: self.followArray)
        query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                self.postImage.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                for object in objects! {
                    self.postImage.append(object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                    self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)
                    self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)
                }



            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
            self.activityView.stopAnimating()
            self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()


        })

           }
                    })
    }
```

And here is how I am pulling to refresh:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refresher.addTarget(self, action: "reload", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        collectionView.addSubview(refresher)
        loadPosts()

    }


    func reload() {

        collectionView.reloadData()
        refresher.endRefreshing()


    }
```

Comment: Your reload function doesn't actually fetch  the data again. It just throws away all of the collection view cells and loads the same data back into them. You need to call loadPosts you should check if the data is different and only if it is call reloadData or better yet only reload the items that are different.

Comment: @beyowulf Ahh sounds right! in what way could I reload the items that are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the UUID's are unique for every post, so you can check to see if the count from the previous load is different from the current, then you can see which posts are new, figure out their index path then only reload those index paths. I used sets to determine which id's had been added, which will work assuming you don't want to display the same post twice. There might be a better way of doing it, but in general you need to do something similar to the following:

```
 func loadPosts() {
         self.activityView.startAnimating()
            let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follows")
            followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            self.followArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                            for object in objects! {
                                self.followArray.append(object.valueForKey("following") as! String)

                            }

            let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
            query.limit = self.page
            query.whereKey("username", notContainedIn: self.followArray)
            query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    let oldUUIDArray = self.uuidArray
                    self.postImage.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    for object in objects! {
                        self.postImage.append(object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                        self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)
                        self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)
                    }
                    let uuidOldSet = Set(oldUUIDArray)
                    let uuidNewSet = Set(self.uuidArray)
                    let missingUUIDs = uuidNewSet.subtract(uuidOldSet)
                    let missingUUIDArray = Array(missingUUIDs)
                    let missingUUIDIndexPaths = missingUUIDArray.map{NSIndexPath(forItem:self.uuidArray.indexOf($0)!,inSe ction:0)} 

                    let extraUUIDs = uuidOldSet.subtract(uuidNewSet)
                    let extraUUIDArray = Array(extraUUIDs)
                    let extraUUIDIndexPaths = extraUUIDArray.map{NSIndexPath(forItem:oldUUIDArray.indexOf($0)!,inSection:0)}
                    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    if extraUUIDIndexPath != nil {
                        self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(extraUUIDIndexPaths)
                    }
                    if missingUUIDIndexPaths != nil {self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(missingUUIDIndexPaths)}
                    }, completion: nil)


                    } else {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }

                self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                self.activityView.stopAnimating()
                self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()


            })

               }
                        })
        }

    func reload() {

            self.loadPosts()
            refresher.endRefreshing()


        }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that! sounds promising.. I just copied and pasted it, just getting these 2 small error http://i.stack.imgur.com/nOxtz.png

Comment: Should be `let uuidNewSet = Set(self.uuidArray)`

Comment: What about the uuidNewArray part? should that be NewSet?

Comment: Sorry should be: ` let missingUUIDIndexPaths = missingUUIDArray.map{NSIndexPath(forItem:self.uuidArray.indexOf($0)!,inSection:0)} `

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pqjad.png got this error unfortunately! Not sure I have ever seen it before..I am also creating a video of my problem, to help understand my problem

Comment: Think it needs to be `self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(missingUUIDIndexPaths)`

Comment: It seems to be working! But as I don't want to show the posts of a user im following, when I follow them the posts need to be removed off that VC. When I follow someone and then reload the page I get another rror and crash! shall I open a new question? heres a video of the problem before https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qizaAbUnzYQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/REt8j.png thats the other error, if you like I'll create a new question

Comment: Can you reproduce it? Try setting a breakpoint on the highlighted line check if missingUUIDIndexPaths is equal to nil, if that's the problem wrap `self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(missingUUIDIndexPaths)` in an if statement that says `if missingUUIDIndexPaths != nil`

Comment: I added that, I think we're getting there! You don't know how much I appreciate your help!! I got another error down at CellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm guessing thats because its expecting an image but not getting one. http://i.stack.imgur.com/bx3Ca.png

Comment: I think what is needed is a way to remove them, basically the opposite of what its doing. I tried deleteItems... but didn't work, error again

Comment: I think you're right. I'll edit my answer to take care of that.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I actually have a couple more jobs that I need doing, and I was planning on hiring a developer. If your interested send me message in chat on here!

Comment: Hey, I was just wondering if this was possible for a tableView...As your help was great with fixing the collectionView, and I am getting a similar problem with the tableView...Is it possible to do the same thing? If so I'll post a new question and give you the link

Comment: Yes. It's possible. The main difference is you don't use batch update. You call tableView.beginUpdates() insert and delete, then call tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: Great I wasn't sure...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043809/call-batch-updates-with-tableview I posted a question...If you'd like the reputation :)