# Call batch updates with TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

With a collection I would perform batch updates to prevent it from flashing...Now I'm trying to do the same with a table, if possible...

In a previous post I did it as the answer shows....[CollectionView flash when reloadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587847/collectionview-flash-when-reloaddata/35589255?noredirect=1#comment59734461_35589255)

here's my query, as I think I need to add it in there:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
query.limit = self.page
query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
query.whereKey("username", notContainedIn: self.followArray)
query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        //let oldUUIDArray = self.uuidArray
        self.images.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.tableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


        for object in objects! {

            if let _ = object.valueForKey("textPost") as? PFFile {
                // this must be a text post
                let post = ImageStruct(dataTypeInit: 0,
                    uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String,
                    textInit: object.valueForKey("textPost") as! PFFile)


               self.images.append(post)
            } else {
                // this must be an image
                    // this must be a text post
                    let post = ImageStruct(dataTypeInit: 1,
                        uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String,
                        imageInit: object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)


                    self.images.append(post)
            }}
        self.tableView1.reloadData()
    }
```

If anyone can help me change it from batch updates to the tableView version that would be great....

Comment: Are you sure that you are reloading the tableView in your main thread?

Comment: Everything shows correctly, but as I mentioned din the post I linked above when I reload the TBV it flashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
query.limit = self.page
query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
query.whereKey("username", notContainedIn: self.followArray)
query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        let oldImageArray = self.images
        self.images.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.tableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let oldImageArray = self.images

        for object in objects! {

            if let _ = object.valueForKey("textPost") as? PFFile {
                // this must be a text post
                let post = ImageStruct(dataTypeInit: 0,
                    uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String,
                    textInit: object.valueForKey("textPost") as! PFFile)


               self.images.append(post)
            } else {
                // this must be an image
                    // this must be a text post
                    let post = ImageStruct(dataTypeInit: 1,
                        uuidInit: object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String,
                        imageInit: object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)


                    self.images.append(post)
            }}
        let newImageUUIDArray = self.images.map({return $0.uuid})
        let oldImageUUIDArray = oldImageArray.map({return $0.uuid})
        let oldImageSet = Set(oldImageUUIDArray)
        let newImageSet = Set(newImageUUIDArray)
        let missingImages = newImageSet.subtract(oldImageSet)

        let missingImageIndexPaths = Array(missingImages).map{NSIndexPath(forRow:newImageUUIDArray.indexOf($0)!,inSection:0)}

        let removedImages = oldImageSet.subtract(newImageSet)
        let removedImageIndexPaths = Array(removedImages).map{NSIndexPath(forRow:oldImageUUIDArray.indexOf($0)!,inSection:0)}



     self.tableView1.beginUpdate()
            if missingImageIndexPath.count != 0 {
       self.tableView1.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(missingImageIndexPaths,withRowAnimation:.Right)
}
            if removedImageIndexPath.count != 0 {
              self.tableView1.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(removedImageIndexPaths,withRowAnimation:.Fade)
}
            self.tableView1.endUpdates()
        }
```

You could factor the determining of new image and deleted image index paths into other functions to make it more readable. But in general this will only update rows that have changed rather than reloading all of the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this again! But as Images is a struct I have a few error... I have edited [oldImageSet & newImageSet] already http://i.stack.imgur.com/NA7wr.png

Comment: Did you add `let oldImageArray = self.images` after `if error == nil {`? Why are you saying `Set(arrayLiteral:self.images[0].image!)`?

Comment: I did, because its a struct not a normal array, here's a screenshot of the errors without changing it http://i.stack.imgur.com/xP9cf.png

Comment: Yeah you have flatten the array to the UUID then do the set operation. I changed my answer.

Comment: Yeh now it allows it all but I get this in the log, and nothing loads on the screen: failure in [UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1506

Comment: Think you need to make sure the count of the index path arrays are not 0

Comment: Ok I got it working when I launch my app, but when I pull to refresh I get that error again, any idea? I checked the update, but still it doesn't seem to remove or add new posts..

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you! I just tried this on another tableView which has a header, but I get that error from before again...But if I remove the header and change the numberOfRows(to posts.count and not 1) and numberOfSections(to 1 from posts.count) it works..? is there another way if you have a header?

Comment: Instead of delete/insertRowsAtIndexPaths call delete/insertSections. There's an example of deleting sections here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748089/delete-uitable-sections-dynamically-with-commiteditingstyle-in-swift

Comment: Hey, I checked that example but couldn't really figure it out... But I posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353836/inserting-removing-cells-from-tableview-with-beginupdates

Comment: Hey I have a bounty for a similar question, would you be able to check it out please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959227/another-solution-instead-of-tableview-reloaddata